# How to extend plot line value outside the grey area or outside the chart in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to extend plotline along with value outside the grey background or outside the chart area using highchart.
Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/mncfy80p/

Wanted to customize chart like below image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbHGh.png`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the space occupied by `xAxis` and use `plotBands` instead of `plotBackgroundColor` property.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    max: 3,
    plotBands: [{
        color: "#D3D3D3",
        from: -1,
        to: 2.5
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7jcqek36/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands